# Deduce longest paths

Tags: java, path

I have a list of `Path` (`java.nio.file`).

For example

```
/a/b/c/d
/a/b/c
/a/b/
/a/x/y/z
/a/x/
```

Out of these paths I need to retrieve only the longest paths.

For example,
`/a/b/c/d` and `/a/x/y/z` are the longest paths.

How should I retrieve by using or not using any of the methods in the Path interface in java?

Comment: path.getNameCount() maybe? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PathTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/a/b/c/d";
        Path p = Paths.get(path);
        int num = p.getNameCount();
        System.out.println(num);  // prints 4
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the leaf node?

Comment: Use `p.getName(num-1)` or `p.getName(p.getNameCount()-1)`